# Picklist is not showing on the page

Tags: custom-field, picklist

i hope you all is good....

i have some problem with my page. as a admin i am able to see the field name and related picklist dropdown on the page.

But as user i am not able to see the picklist dropdown but only see the field name.

Could you please help me here where can i change...it's related to profile access or something other configuration that i am missing......

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: can you specify user means any other profile rather than system admin.And it is custom picklist can you elaborate@Vivek113

Comment: For demo purpose i have setup 4 user in my org and i am admin of the org and assign one profile to all the users.

Comment: And yes i have added one custom picklist in both of the profile system admin and newly created profile

Comment: You have 2 picklist fields, or do you mean permissions to 1 field to both profiles?

Comment: No i have one picklist but other users are not able to view the picklist except system admin ...yes it's right...also i have check the field accessibility and field visibility but both are fine mean visible and editable

Comment: Page layout's are different or same for system admin can you check that @Vivek113

Comment: No there is same page layout is used for both the profile

Comment: So if user have the able to view field label name and unable to view field values means field level access required.@Vivek113

Comment: yes that you correct but in this case user is able to view the field label but unable to see picklist dropdown(box)

Comment: This is not a VF page, is it?

Comment: Do you have Record Types on the object - if so the picklist values need to be made available for the relevant RT that the user is accessing on the object. The other scenario where this often happens is with a dependent picklist and making sure that the profile can see both the master and dependent picklists.